# WORDPRESS como ejecutar shortcode antes de enviar un correo e incluir el contenido en el mensaje

Tags: php, base-de-datos, wordpress

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Necesito desarrollar un plugin para wordpress que en un momento dado, personaliza y envía una serie de emails al usuario. El contenido de los correos se personaliza en la administración con wp_editor, al guardar, se incluye un option con el contenido en html en la bbdd.
He creado varios shortcodes que permiten la personalización de los emails con algunos parámetros para que el usuario pueda añadirlos en el lugar que quiera del contenido del correo.

Cuando quiero enviar el mail, recojo el option referente al contenido del email que corresponda y lo guardo en $message, pero al recibir el correo veo los shortcodes sin ejecutar.

¿Como podría envíar los shortcodes ejecutados en el mail? Los shortcodes tienen html con datos específicos para cada momento.

Este es el código del area de texto

```
if (isset($_POST['guardar_contenido_mails'])) {

    $datos_email_privada = $_POST['area_email_privada'];


    if ($allowEdit == true) {
        $datos_email_privada = update_option('contenido_emails_privada', $datos_email_privada);
    } else {
        $datos_email_privada = update_option('contenido_emails_privada', $datos_email_privada, null, 'no');
        wp_cache_delete('contenido_emails_privada');
    }
}
<div>
    <p>Este correo se envía al usuario cuando la inscripción depende de la aceptación de la administración</p>
        <?php 
            $settings = array(
                'textarea_rows' => 15,
                'tabindex' => 1,
                'wpautop' => false
                //'quicktags' => false
             );
             wp_editor($datos_email_privada, 'area_email_privada', $settings);
        ?>
</div>
```

Este es mi código resumido, obviando los header, to, etc.:

```
//Recojo los datos
$datos_email_privada = get_option('contenido_emails_privada', 'Personalice su contenido');

if ($tipo_mail == 'previo_validacion') {

    $message = $header_mail;
    $message .= '<div style="'.$separacion.'">';

    //Aquí incluyo el contenido del mail
    $message .= $datos_email_privada;

    $message .= '</div>';
    $message .= $footer_mail;

}
```

Antes de enviar, he intentado añadir un filtro para habilitar los shortcodes pero no funciona

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'do_shortcode' );


if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    return true;
};
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solucionado el tema gracias a este enlace.

https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/shortcodes-in-automated-emails

Con hacer un do_shortcode($foo) al traer los datos, ya convierte los tags correctamente.

```
//Aquí incluyo el contenido del mail
$message .= do_shortcode($datos_email_privada);
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Saludos!